# Как правильно: "поставки древесины с собственного лесного фонда" или "поставки древесины из собственного лесного фонда"?

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно: *Поставки древесины осуществляются преимущественно **с** собственного лесного фонда* или *Поставки древесины осуществляются преимущественно **из** собственного лесного фонда*?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно ***из***. Это как *"с Москвы"* вместо *"из Москвы"* — областной разговорный вариант, но не соответствующий литературной норме.

***Небольшое уточнение:***

Я воспринял *фонд* как ***учреждение*** — тогда ответ в силе. Если же под *фондом* подразумевается ***база***, на которой хранится древесина или изделия из древесины, или ***площадка, территория,*** тогда правильно сказать ***с***.